# Laravel homestead installation issues

Tags: laravel-4

I am tying to install laravel/homestead i went through the docs 
and at the final stage am having this issues this is my code.

```
    ➜ Homestead git:(master) ✗>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:410:in `initialize': Permission denied - /home/ubilli/.vagrant.d/data/lock.machine-action-0edeb9a5c0c9e5108f108257c012b604.lock (Errno::EACCES)
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:410:in `open'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:410:in `block in lock'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:434:in `lock'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:409:in `lock'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
➜ Homestead git:(master) ✗>sudo vagrant up
[sudo] password for ubilli: 
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on Vagrant Cloud, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead"]
Error: Couldn't resolve host 'vagrantcloud.com'
➜ Homestead git:(master) ✗>sudo vagrant up
```

this is my homestead.yaml file what can i do to correct this issue.

```
    ---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: /home/ubilli/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - /home/ubilli/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /home/ubilli/laravel4app
      to: /var/www/laravel

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by checking the permissions of this directory (/home/ubilli) since it seems you can't write to it:

> Permission denied - /home/ubilli/.vagrant.d/

This has happened to me where my own home directory has changed to root ownership.  Try:

> sudo chown -R ubilli:ubilli /home/ubilli/

To reset your whole directory back to the user account.  Vagrant needs to write to that directory since that is where it downloads the box file to.